# mongodb search query - returns all results (non matching ones too)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

This is a sample from MEAN stack website, 
I require the query to return parameters that match ' exactly ' with the input. 
Please view the image attached to understand the issue better.

[Search Query Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwfsK.jpg)

Any hint on this issue ? (I'm a beginner so please elaborate a little) 
-TIA :)

---

```
  Input for the search from the browser 

  { body: { hp: 1, length: 1, diameter: 1, voltage: 1 } }
```

---

```
 // mongo schema 

  var CableSchema = new schema({
        body : {
            "hp": {
                type: Number
            },
            "length": {
                type: Number
            },
            "diameter": {                      
                type: Number
            },
            "voltage": {                        
                type: Number
            },
            "cost": {
                type: Number
            },

            "type": {
                type: String,
                default: "Cable"
            }
        }
    });

-----------------------------------------------------------
  // Result from Search Query obtained in console 

    [ { body:
         { type: 'Cable',
           cost: 1,
           voltage: 1,
           diameter: 1,
           length: 1,
           hp: 1 },
        __v: 0,
        _id: 5820246086d42a3c269ad9f2 },
      { body:
         { type: 'Cable',
           cost: 2,
           voltage: 2,
           diameter: 2,
           length: 2,
           hp: 2 },
        __v: 0,
        _id: 5820249086d42a3c269ad9f3 } ]`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys 'hp','length' etc are inside the body object of cable schema. So to refer 'hp' use 'body.hp' in query

Change your query to

```
var query = Cable.find({'body.hp' : parseInt(reqHp) , 'body.length' : parseInt(reqLen),
        'body.diameter' : parseInt(reqDia) ,'body.voltage' : parseInt(reqVol)})
```

Comment: Ty, I made above changes . Unfortunately it now returns : " No results found "

Comment: Convert the values to integer using ParseInt

Comment: they are defined as integers in schema, applied parseInt() method. the query is still broken, I also tried using $gte method it does not work either.

Comment: please post console.log(req.body)

Answer (score 0):

The confusion was with assignment - 1body was from req body and the other one was from '2body' schema 
I needed to use 1body.2body  to reach inside for the data.

```js
    var reqHP = req.body.body.hp;
    var reqLen = req.body.body.length;
    var reqDia = req.body.body.diameter;
    var reqVol = req.body.body.voltage;
    var reqCost = req.body.body.cost;
```